# How to change url from m3u8 to .ts

Tags: url, video, stream, m3u8, iptv

I'm trying to make an iptv link work on my receiver
this is the original link that i want to convert

> http://s7.iapi.com:8000/re-NBA/index.m3u8?token=BzyIVQOtO77MTw

and this is the format that i want to reach in the end.

> http://pro-vision.dyndns.pro:12580/live/laurent/laurent/2791.ts

Answer (score 2):

An m3u8 file is just a text file that acts as an index for media streams - it will contain 'pointers' to the location of video and audio streams themselves.

A TS file is a 'container' that contains the video and audio streams themselves - i.e. the actual video and audio data.

You can't simply convert any m3u8 to a ts file or stream, but you can extract from the m3u8 file a ts file URL, which maybe is what you want.

If you look at the overview section of the m3u8 definition there is a very simple example which is maybe the best way of understanding this:

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-19

The m3u8 file includes the ts references and can be seen in this extract from the above document:

```html
#EXTM3U
   #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10

   #EXTINF:9.009,
   http://media.example.com/first.ts
   #EXTINF:9.009,
   http://media.example.com/second.ts
   #EXTINF:3.003,
   http://media.example.com/third.ts
```

The numbers here refer to the length of the stream. More complex examples allow you have multiple variants of a particular stream, to allow different bit rate versions of a video for Adaptive Bit Rate (ABR) streaming for example.

Comment: thank you Mick for answer but the original link turn out to work fine on my receiver and the problem solved